# Sails hook passport

Tags: express, sails.js, passport.js, waterline, sails-hook

I'm trying to implement Passport strategies into a sails hook, like this I can share on multiple project.

When I try to log I have this error :

```
Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails-hook-passport/node_modules/passport-github/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:30:30)
    at /Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails-hook-passport/api/controllers/AuthController.js:163:11
    at Strategy.strategy.success (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails-hook-passport/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:194:18)
    at verified (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails-hook-passport/node_modules/passport-twitter/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:169:16)
    at returnResults (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic.js:168:9)
    at /Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic.js:74:16
    at /Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:82:7
    at Object.async.each (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:121:20)
    at /Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:425:11
    at /Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:564:5
    at Object.async.each (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:121:20)
    at _buildChildOpts (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:453:9)
    at _execChildOpts (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:421:8)
    at /Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:80:10
    at bound (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/Users/jaumard/IdeaProjects/HookPassportTest/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
```

I read that I have to add some middleware in config/http.js

```
middleware: {

    passportInit    : require('passport').initialize(),
    passportSession : require('passport').session(),

    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'passportInit',
      'passportSession',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ]
  }
```

All it's working after this but I'm under an installable hook and don't want to manually change http.js, is there a way to modify this from the hook ? Or fix the error without adding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to init passport.js in your middleware but want to avoid having to manually edit http.js in each of your projects. To do that you'd create an [installable hook](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks/installablehooks.html) like so:

```
module.exports = function passware(sails) {

sails.config.http.middleware = {

    passportInit    : require('passport').initialize(),
    passportSession : require('passport').session(),

    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'passportInit',
      'passportSession',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ]
  }

  return {};
}
```

To use it you simply copy the hook into your `node_modules` or `npm publish` and `npm install` it in your projects.

Comment: That's exactly what I want ! It's works great now ! I already have my installable hook but I didn't know modify config like this was working ! I will clean my code and put it on my repo here https://github.com/jaumard/sails-hook-passport if someone is interested in this